# BotDetect Captcha Issue: New Session Initialized on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, captcha, botdetect

Good Day!

I just need some help regarding this issue that I'm encountering using BotDetect Captcha.

Issue: Session Troubleshooting: New Session Initialized on Postback, potential timeout or Session resume problem

I'm using version 4.1.0.0 of BotDetect.dll in asp.net/SharePoint site. 
The issue is happening upon clicking the Submit button in the page and when it postback to validate the page inputs, the captcha section will fail and show this issue.

This is the code that I use to validate the captcha input:

```
 isValid = BotDetectCaptcha.Validate(CaptchaCodeTextBox.Text.Trim().ToUpper());

if (isValid){ //code here }
```

The thing that makes me wonder is that this code is working fine in my Dev environment which I'm using default values in the web.config of the site. 
However, when we deployed this to the staging server, this error occurs. 
One thing to point is the sessionState in dev is just inProc and in staging, it is using a custom sessionState to an SQL DataBase - and I'm not sure if this is the cause.

Here is the sessionState setting in staging:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" timeout="60" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<table>;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15" />
```

I have no control of the settings of the iis/site in the server so this is getting harder on my end so I'm hoping someone might be able to point directions on what to check or troubleshoot.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It does _sound_ like what you pointed out re: InProc v SQL - why don't you check by creating a new Session variable and see if that persists in the above flow?

Comment: It turns out to be a server issue after all. Something with regards to network blocking connections to some resources.Tried to deploy the same to other server and it is working. Thank you for the insight as well @EdSF

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a server issue after all. Something with regards to network blocking connections to some resources.Tried to deploy the same to other server and it is working.